# Remove a specific string only if it's in the very end of a code

Tags: regex, perl

I'm parsing a html file to extract part of its text to create an epub. The problem is that in the text extracted sometimes the last paragraph is an empty one that I would like to remove. So... how can I remove this blank paragraph (and any additional blank spaces after that) with the condition that there's no additional text later on in any other line of code?

For example:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.”</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error...</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
<p>Omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

So, what can I do to remove only this last instance of `<p>&nbsp;</p>` (and any additional blank spaces/newlines after that) from the code above?

I have tried using this negative lookahead `<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*?(?!<p>)` on perl-regex to exclude later paragraphs from the search, but it still finds the previous instances of `<p>&nbsp;</p>` and I only need to remove this paragraph when it's the last one in the file.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT-1:**

To be clear, I want this:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.”</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error...</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
<p>Omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

to become this:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.”</p>
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error...</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.”</p>
<p>Omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem.</p>
```

**i.e.** I want to remove the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` only in the last line (where there's no other text after it), so I want to know which perl-regex search I should use to find only this particular instance of this string so I can replace it with nothing and with that remove it from the code.

**EDIT-2.:**

Based on a suggestion by ikegami, I used `\s*(?><p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)(?!<p>)\s*` as the search string to find only the last blank paragraph (`<p>&nbsp;</p>`)of the html code to be removed. What really made the difference in his answer seems to have been the use of an atomic grouping `(?>...)`. Without it, I was picking other instances of the same string from other lines of the code that I didn't want. Not sure why (really not an expert on regex), but that's what I got from my tests.

I'm just using some basic find/replace operations of perl-regex in an ebook editor to clean the code, so I'm not sure about how it will behave under other circumstances. Anyway, I appreciate the other attempts of helping me, some of which were even too technical for me to grasp and I hope this answer will help someone in the future with a similar problem. Thank you again!

Comment: `remove this blank paragraph` If it's blank, how do you know it's a paragraph ?

Comment: Here is a good way `<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*$` to find it. Then replace it. Or if you have many blank paragraphs, then this `\s*(?:<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)+$`

Comment: @sln The blank paragraph `<p>&nbsp;</p>` in the middle of the text leaves a gap that indicates a "section break" and, yeah, the blank paragraph in the end technically doesn't make a difference, but I just want to remove anything that's not useful, so I only want to remove the last instance of it in the end of the code.And unfortunately your regex still picks the other intances. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: `s/<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*?(?!<p>)//s` should be `s/<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*+(?=(?:(?!<p>).)*\z)//s`

Comment: `And unfortunately your regex still picks the other intances. Thanks, anyway!` Well, anyway you're welcome. Be sure you know what your looking at when you say things like this. The EOS (end of string) anchor insures it doesn't pick up any other instances...

Comment: It seems that you only need to process a fragment of HTML that is obtained by another tool.  I'd just like to let you know that there are excellent Perl modules for parsing HTML.  For instance, see [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~kentnl/HTML-Tree-5.06/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm#elementify), which inherits from a number of others. You can get a taste for what you can do by also looking through [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/~kentnl/HTML-Tree-5.06/lib/HTML/Element.pm), which it uses heavily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use regexes at all. As you'll see, that's the complicated approach.

---

**If you want to check make sure there's no `<p>` anywhere after the `<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*`**

You want to check that none of the the following characters are the start of `<p>`.

You need to check that all of the following characters aren't the start of `<p>`.

You want:

```
s/(?><p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)(?=(?:(?!<p>).)*\z)//s
```

Other changes:

- The `?` in `\s*?` makes no sense; you don't want to match the fewest.
- `(?>...)` prevents the pattern from starting to look for `<p>` inside of `<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*`. In this particular pattern (but not the one below), it simply acts as an optimization.

---

**If you want to check make sure there's no `<p>` immediately after `<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*`**

You want:

```
s/(?><p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)(?!<p>)//
```

Comment: My knowledge of coding is basic at best, so I can't even try to argue with you. Most of this stuff still goes way over my head most of the time. I only use regex to facilitate my ebook editing occasionally.

Either way, based on your suggestion, I used `\s*(?><p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)(?!<p>)\s*` as my search string and `\n` as my replace string and it worked! 
Thank you very much!

Comment: `(?>\s*<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)(?!<p>)` would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use the `$` anchor.

Long answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = $ARGV[0] or die 'filename required!';

# Not certain what encoding your file is in
open (my $fh, '< :encoding(UTF-8)', $fn) 
    or die "could not open file '$fn': $!";

# slurp entire file
my $content = do{ local $/; <$fh>; };
close $fh;

# If it ends with the blank paragraph followed by newline/tab/space,
# overwrite the file
if ( $content =~ s /<p>&nbsp;<\/p>[\n\s\t\r]*$// ){
    open (my $fh, '> :encoding(UTF-8)', $fn)
        or die "could not open file '$fn' to write: $!";
    print $fh $content;
    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: I got a sense from a comment that they have that HTML fragment in a running program of some sort, perhaps in a string. Then this approach is even more clearly suited.  (There are clearly no trailing HTML document-level tags.)  Btw, I like to stick the `open` statement inside the `do` block. There is also no need for `close` then.

Answer (score 0):

```
EDIT-2.:

Based on a suggestion by ikegami, I used 
\s*(?><p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)(?!<p>)\s* as the search string to find only 
the last blank paragraph (<p>&nbsp;</p>)of the html code to be 
removed. What really made the difference in his answer seems to have 
been the use of an atomic grouping (?>...). Without it, I was picking 
other instances of the same string from other lines of the code that I
didn't want. Not sure why (really not an expert on regex), but that's 
what I got from my tests.
```

You should not use something you don't understand.
In reality, you should learn regex instead of asking somebody to do it for you.

Just a short education here, the same is achieved with this regex
`\s*<p>&nbsp;</p>(?>\s*)(?!<p>)\s*`
in that the juxtaposition of these two `(?>\s*)` `(?!<p>)` prevents
the engine from giving up a single whitespace to satisfy the assertion.
If you had no whitespace between paragraph markers, an atomic group is
not necessary.

To further explore this, the assertion `(?!<p>)` presumes there exists
a paragraph marker *directly* after `<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*`.
This is a bad choice for a design. If there is no paragraph marker there
it will match it, *even if it exists further down somewhere*.

---

Other design considerations:

You state this is html, which means there *will* be other tags following
the last `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. This means you shouldn't need the EOS anchor `$` or `\z`in the 
regex, unless you use a regex that @ikegami suggests `(?><p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)(?=(?:(?!<p>).)*\z)`
which need's a `(?s)` to go with it.

However, this regex is a *terrible* idea !!
Each time it finds a `<p>&nbsp;</p>` it has to stop and search all the way to
the end of the string.
If you have 500  `<p>&nbsp;</p>` in the document, it is mostly equivalent to searching
the same document text 500 times.

---

***The Safe and Sane approach***

---

This way -> `(?s).*\K<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*`

It just goes directly to the last one via `(?s).*`
then skips that part of the match using `\K`,
leaving only the `<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*` to be replaced with nothing.

**Benchmark test:**
The target sample contains 10 duplicates of the OP's sample @ 30 `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

```
@ikegami Regex:   (?s)(?><p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)(?=(?:(?!<p>).)*\z)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    3.24 s,   3236.42 ms,   3236424 µs


Safe and Sane Regex:   (?s).*\K<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.10 s,   102.04 ms,   102044 µs
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "You should not use something you don't understand." Isn't experimenting with something you don't fully understand part of learning? Specially for someone who's just beginning? And I really didn't exactly ask someone "to do it for me". I tried/searched many different things on my own before I finally yielded and asked for help here (for the very first time, btw). Maybe my approach was wrong, and I apologize for that, but I can't see what I did so differently from other people here. I appreciate your input, but I think you were unnecessarily harsh in your phrasing.

Comment: And... Yeah, I've been trying to learn regex, but it really doesn't help when depending on the language and support the tools your are using have, the syntax can differ quite a bit. For instance, I not even could try to use the `\z` anchor because it's not supported by the tools I'm using and, to be honest, I not even knew that `\K` existed before. Anyway, thank you for your response and because of that I learned some interesting new things today.

Comment: @CAVR - Yeah, a lot of people here will post any answer for quick points. Unfortunately for you, you don't know the difference between good and bad. That's the fallacy of the SO reward system. I will call a banana rotten when I see it which I point out for your benefit. I on the other hand have an interest in seeing people learn regex correctly and not get any bad habits. Regex is a precision instrument, like a chainsaw is. It can carve a sculpture or it can cut your arm off. Come back and re-read my post when you become intermediate level, it will fall into place for you.